# In a subset $Y=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x^2+2y^2+3z^2=6\}$ of a metric space show that a Cauchy sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(\mathbb{R}^3 ,||)$ a metric space and $Y=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: x^2+2y^2+3z^2=6\}$

i) Show that each sequence Cauchy of elements of $Y$ converges to a point of $Y$.

ii) Show that each sequence of elements of $Y$ has a convergent sequence

I think for the first part Ii have to show that $Y$ is a closed set but I am not sure how to show it.
For the second par, if I show that the sequence is bounded, then I think that it has a convergent sequence.

I observe that $6-x^2\geq0 \Rightarrow x^2\leq6\Rightarrow |x| \leq\sqrt{6}$

Similarly $6-2y^2\geq 0 \Rightarrow y^2 \leq3 \Rightarrow |y| \leq\sqrt{3} $

and

$ 6-3z^2 \geq0 \Rightarrow z^2 \leq2 \Rightarrow|z] \leq\sqrt{2}$

I really need help.Thank you.

Comment: Is it the usual metric on $\mathbf R^3$?

Comment: Yes we have the usual metric

Comment: That's what I thought, but I wanted to be sure. In this case, my hint is valid.

Comment: So in your answer Y is bounded by 0 and 6 so each sequence of elements of Y has a convergent sequence and i don't have to prove anything more.Am i right?

Comment: Yes. Anyway, $Y$ is compact, and consequently complete.

Comment: But for the first part i an not sure that i understand your idea.You mean that {6} is a closed set and as Y is the inverse image of the following continue function is also closed?

Comment: Yes, the inverse image of a closed set by a continuous function is closed.

Comment: So that is all and i haven't to prove anything else for the solution to be complete?
I am really grateful for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help! Kαλησπέρα!

Comment: Eυχαριστώ πολύ!It means thanks in greek.

Comment: I know that – I have friends in Athens (and I learnt ancient greek in high school).

Comment: @Bernard Here   $diam(Y)=\sqrt{6}$
 Am I right ??

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how one computes the diameter of an ellipsoid.

Comment: I  would rather conclude that $\operatorname{diam}(Y)\le\sqrt 6$.

Comment: @Bernardwe have $$0\leq x^2+y^2+z^2\leq x^2+2y^2+3z^2=6 :(1)$$
$ \Rightarrow 0\leq  x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 6 \Rightarrow 0 \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \leq \sqrt{6} $
$\Rightarrow 0\leq d(x,y,z) \leq \sqrt{6 }$
So $diam(Y) \leq\sqrt{6}$ eq.(2) Am i right? How to proove that Y is bounded. And is the eq.(2) enough in order to say that $Y$ is bounded ?

Comment: Yes: $Y$ ins contained in the closed ball centred at the origin,  with radius $\sqrt 6$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$Y$ is the inverse image of the set $\{6\}\subset \mathbf R$ (closed in $\mathbf R$), by the continuous function
\begin{align}
\mathbf R^3&\longrightarrow\mathbf R, \\
(x,y,z)&\longmapsto x^2+2y^2+3z^2.
\end{align}

Toshow $Y$ is bounded, observe that $\;0\le x^2+y^2+z^2 \le x^2+2y^2+3z^2$.